# Has casting (using as) in Swift changed recently (maybe in the latest beta)?

Tags: xcode, swift

I've just gone back to a project I started ages ago and the compiler is throwing out hundreds of errors about objects not being convertible (to objects which subclass them), and suggesting I use as! instead of as, to force the cast.

Is this a bug in the latest X-Code beta, or has the down-casting syntax changed?

Comment: It is well-documented in the Xcode beta release notes! There is also a Edit->Convert->To Latest Swift ... option in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax has changed for Swift 1.2. See [Apple's blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23) about it.

Here's a summary from their article:

> Swift 1.2 separates the notions of guaranteed conversion and forced
>   conversion into two distinct operators. Guaranteed conversion is still
>   performed with the `as` operator, but forced conversion now uses the `as!`
>   operator. The `!` is meant to indicate that the conversion may fail.
>   This way, you know at a glance which conversions may cause the program
>   to crash.